# Synonym for "ungoaled"

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to say:

> Possibly **aimless/non-targeted/ungoaled*** rehabilitation may cause patients exclusion from physical therapy.

*there is no goal setting for rehabilitation, meaning that patients receive rather coincidental care

Which word would be correct to use?

Comment: Perhaps **undirected**?

Comment: And what I take this to be aiming at is that it's not the rehabilitation but the lack of following a required course that precludes the patients from receiving further free physical therapy.